# What member of sentence is the infinitive in the passive voice?

Tags: grammar

If we convert the "verb+object+infinite" sentence like "I know him to go there" (where "him to go" is the direct object)from the active voice into the passive one, than we'll get "He's known to go there" where the object "him" becomes the subject "he", but what member of the sentence will " to go" be. Will it be an adverb of a purpose or something?

Comment: It's the complement of the verb "know"/"known", just like in the first sentence.

Comment: Your analysis of "to go there" is incorrect in that it's not the object of "know". The object is just "him", and the infinitival clause is "to go there", which is complement of "know". In the passive construction "to go there" is again complement of "know", just as it is in the active voice.

Comment: Is it an adverbial complement?

Comment: How can it be a complement of "known" if only a transitive verb can have an object complement and known isn't a transitive one cuz it's used in the passive voice

Comment: @PetroProbka I didn't say it was an object complement. Complements have a wide range of functions, not just object complement. In a passive clause like the one in your example, the infinitival clause is complement of "known". Similarly in a passive clause like "The accident was [seen by everyone]" where the bracketed clause is complement of "was". Basic grammar, really.

Answer (score 1):

The direct object in "I know him to go there" is "him".  The infinitive does not modify "him", but is a complement of "know". The verb "know" allows this structure (although this particular example sounds a little odd).

In the passive "He is known to go there." the infinitive has the same role and the same meaning. Know is a catenative verb and can be followed by a to-infinitive to complete the clause.

The passive form is natural enough, the active sense could be better expressed as "I know (that) he goes there" since the verb "know" also licences a finite content clause as a complement.

Comment: "I know him to go there" is not only odd, it's not idiomatic, and no native English speaker would ever say that.  [check out the google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+know+him+to+go&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3).