# Infinitive in passive voice

Tags: grammar

If we put the "verb+object+infinite" sentence like "I know him to go there" from the active voice into the passive one, than we'll get "He's known to go there" where the object "him" becomes the subject "he", but what member of the sentence will "to go" be? Will it be an adverb of a reason?

Comment: You asked the same question yesterday here [link](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/345619/what-member-of-sentence-is-the-infinitive-in-the-passive-voice)